# Overlay a fetched image over itself (with transformations) with Cloudinary

Tags: overlay, fetch, cloudinary

I would like to generate an image with to versions of the same fetch image, like this one:

[image]

Here are the two versions:

The background: https://res.cloudinary.com/nho/image/fetch/w_1024,h_512,c_thumb,g_auto,q_auto,f_auto/e_brightness:80/e_blur:3000/https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2016/08/a-bridge-not-so-far.jpg

[image]

The overlay: https://res.cloudinary.com/nho/image/fetch/w_1024,h_512,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto/https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2016/08/a-bridge-not-so-far.jpg

[image]

I don't understand how to do that with the documentation for [overlays](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#image_and_text_overlays) and for [chained transformations](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#chained_transformations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Cloudinary does not currently support using fetched images for overlay purposes.
If the source for these images (e.g. `https://nicolas-hoizey.com`) is known in advance then [automatic-upload](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images#auto_upload_remote_images) may be preferable.</strike>

Then, achieving the desired effect is done with the following transformation sequence: 
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_500/u_upload:2016:08:a-bridge-not-so-far,ar_2:1,c_scale,e_blur:2000,o_70,w_0.7,c_crop/h_1.0,fl_relative.layer_apply/2016/08/a-bridge-not-so-far.jpg

UPDATE:
Cloudinary just announced a new support for overlaying dynamically fetched images. This is done by encoding the remote URL to Base64, e.g. (rails):

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64("https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2016/08/a-bridge-not-so-far.jpg")
 => "aHR0cHM6Ly9uaWNvbGFzLWhvaXpleS5jb20vMjAxNi8wOC9hLWJyaWRnZS1ub3Qtc28tZmFyLmpwZw=="
```

Then the transformation URL will look something like:
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/w_500/u_fetch:aHR0cHM6Ly9uaWNvbGFzLWhvaXpleS5jb20vMjAxNi8wOC9hLWJyaWRnZS1ub3Qtc28tZmFyLmpwZw==,ar_2:1,c_scale,e_blur:2000,o_70,w_0.7,c_crop/h_1.0,fl_relative.layer_apply/https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2016/08/a-bridge-not-so-far.jpg
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a page in Cloudinary documentation where this is explained? I can't find anything about this syntax.

Comment: Hi , check this out: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/206112219-How-to-transform-a-portrait-image-to-landscape-by-adding-blurry-padding let me know if missing anything

Comment: @NicolasHoizey See my updates above, I hope you'll find it useful

Comment: Wow, it looks awesome, I have to try it ASAP, thanks!