# How do I convert the following remote URL to a base64 safe URL with C#?

Tags: c#, base64, url-encoding, cloudinary

I want to fetch remote images and do some image transformation specifically an overlay over an image with cloudinary. But cloudinary only supports 64base safe urls to overlay images.
Lets say I have this following remote image URL.

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15665479_1260320054027269_4201232212927955955_n.jpg?oh=ee01f2ec47b2e972bc12f99d988db241&oe=5946A159
```

How can I encode it to a 64base url? I have been through many SO questions related to the question but none of them were helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: Do they need your URL to be encoded in Base64 or the image to be encoded? You can do both of them pretty easily..

Comment: They need the remote image URL not the image it self. So Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to encode both URL and Image (may not be what you need, but might be useful sometime)

```
string url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15665479_1260320054027269_4201232212927955955_n.jpg?oh=ee01f2ec47b2e972bc12f99d988db241&oe=5946A159";

string encodedUrl = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(url));

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] dataBytes = client.DownloadData(new Uri(url));
    string encodedFileAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(dataBytes);
}
```

Comment: I take this as answer as it does what I asked for but if you please have a look at the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337286/overlay-a-fetched-image-over-itself-with-transformations-with-cloudinary) url and see if you can further help me with the issue.